# html table to excell export using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, export, excellentexport

I have table in HTML like:

```
<table id="prehledPlatidel" class="table table-hover">

      <tr>
<th title="Zařízení na kterém účtenka vznikla.">Zařízení</th>  
<th title="Název platidla.">Platidlo</th>
  <th title="Přijato celkem.">Celkem</th>         
</tr>
<tbody>
<?php 
 $sumaCelkemZaklad = 0;
 while ($dataPlatidla = $vysledek->fetch_assoc()) {
  $sumaCelkemZaklad = $sumaCelkemZaklad + $dataPlatidla['SumaCelkemZaklad'];  
echo('<tr>
     <td>' . $dataPlatidla['Zarizeni']. ' </td>
     <td>' . $dataPlatidla['Platidlo'].'</td>
     <td>' . number_format($dataPlatidla['SumaCelkem'],2,',', ' '). ' ' .$dataPlatidla['Zkratka'].'</td>
     </tr>'
);
}
echo ('
<tr><td><b>Celkem v základní měně</b></td><td></td>
     <td><b>' .number_format($sumaCelkemZaklad,2,',', ' ').   ' Kč</b></td></tr>
</tbody></table>



<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
function fnExcelReport() {
  var tab_text = '<html xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">';
  tab_text = tab_text + '<head><meta charset="UTF-8" /><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet>';

  tab_text = tab_text + '<x:Name>Platidla</x:Name>';

  tab_text = tab_text + '<x:WorksheetOptions><x:Panes></x:Panes></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet>';
  tab_text = tab_text + '</x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml></head><body>';

  tab_text = tab_text + "<table border='1px'>";
  tab_text = tab_text + $('#prehledPlatidel').html();
  tab_text = tab_text + '</table></body></html>';

  var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';

  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");

  if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) {
      if (window.navigator.msSaveBlob) {
          var blob = new Blob([tab_text], {
              type: "application/csv;charset=utf-8;"
          });
          navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, 'PPlatidel<?php echo('PPlatidel_'.$nazevZarizeni.'_'.$datumOd.'-'.$datumDo);?>.xls');
      }
  } else {
      $('#test').attr('href', data_type + ', ' + encodeURIComponent(tab_text));
      $('#test').attr('download', '<?php echo('PPlatidel_'.$nazevZarizeni.'_'.$datumOd.'-'.$datumDo);?>.xls');
  }

}
//]]></script>
```

everything looks good, xls file is downloaded but when Im trying to open it in Excel 2010, an error dialog is displayed that the file is in different format then is the suffix (xls). After the dialog is confirmed, data will be displayed OK.
Thanks for help. M.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to save a file in HTML format, not XLS. The XLS format is a not a plain text file. I don't know how compatible HTML files are with Excel, but you don't have any external libraries available to you, you may be better off writing to a CSV or 2003 Excel XML format file and saving it with the appropriate extension name. Then let Excel handle the exporting.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function exportToExcel(table) {
    debugger;
tableToExcel(table,'Rapor','Excell_Rapor');
}
function getIEVersion()
// Returns the version of Windows Internet Explorer or a -1
// (indicating the use of another browser).
{
    var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
            rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
    }
    return rv;
}

function tableToExcel(table, sheetName, fileName) {
    

    var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./))      // If Internet Explorer
    {
        return fnExcelReport(table, fileName);
    }

    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,',
        templateData = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/plain; charset=UTF-8"/></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>',
        base64Conversion = function (s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) },
        formatExcelData = function (s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function (m, p) { return c[p]; }) }

    $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").show();

    if (!table.nodeType)
        table = document.getElementById(table)

    var ctx = { worksheet: sheetName || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML }

    var element = document.createElement('a');
    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,' + base64Conversion(formatExcelData(templateData, ctx)));
    element.setAttribute('download', fileName);
    element.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    element.click();
    document.body.removeChild(element);

    $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").hide();
}

function fnExcelReport(table, fileName) {
    
    var tab_text = "<table border='2px'>";
    var textRange;

    if (!table.nodeType)
        table = document.getElementById(table)

    $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").show();
    tab_text =  tab_text + table.innerHTML;

    tab_text = tab_text + "</table>";
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<A[^>]*>|<\/A>/g, "");//remove if u want links in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<img[^>]*>/gi, ""); // remove if u want images in your table
    tab_text = tab_text.replace(/<input[^>]*>|<\/input>/gi, ""); // reomves input params

    txtArea1.document.open("txt/html", "replace");
    txtArea1.document.write(tab_text);
    txtArea1.document.close();
    txtArea1.focus();
    sa = txtArea1.document.execCommand("SaveAs", false, fileName + ".xls");
    $("tbody > tr[data-level='0']").hide();
    return (sa);
}
```

Comment: What does this do, and how does it answer the OP's question?